# Debugging Signal R on responding

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr

i'm trying to connect the signalR from Angular 8 to DotNet Core 3. it able to connect success but it hit error during receive the message from DotNet Core to Angular.
no error during broadcast the message from DotNet Core and error when receive the message in Angular.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GLSS.png)

and this is the only information.

Angular SignalR version @microsoft/signalR 3.1.0
DotNet Core 3.0

Comment: You need to provide some code.

Comment: hi @Kiril1512, the problem solve without changing anythings, not sure what happened...